# Is there a pandas functionality to get an None instead of an index error?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a pandas (version 0.25) DataFrame with some indexes. When I'm looking for an index not present in the DataFrame, I (of course) get an KeyError.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [50, 40]}, index = ['alice', 'bob'])
# works, returns age 50:
df.loc['alice']
# does not work, gives KeyError
```

What I would like to have is something like `get` for dictionaries (`{'alice': 50}.get('charlie')`) for DataFrames. The best I could find was

```
df.loc['charlie'] if 'charlie' in df.index else None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.get` which behaves same as the vanilla Python `dict.get` method. So it will return `None` when the key does not exist. We use `Transpose` because its an column index method.

```
df.T.get('charlie')

# returns None
```

```
df.T.get('alice')

age    50
Name: alice, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reindex`:

```
df.reindex(['Charlie'])
```

Output:

```
         age
Charlie  NaN
```